# Tracking Edge on a video

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, canny-operator

I would like to track edge on a video. x and y coordinate of the points on the edge of my object in function of time. I change my image to show only edges with Canny package but there are several edges in my image. I took the x,y coordinate of all the pixels that are edges.

```
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(canny,70,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
x,y = np.where(mask == 255)
pos=np.array([x,y]).T
dist = distance_matrix(pos,pos,threshold=10e6)
```

I want to focus on the bigger edge. I tried to sort them by the number of pixel. First I compute the distance matrix to compute all the neighbors pixels but i did not manage to group all the neighbours pixel with the same label ?

```
entities1,entities2 = np.where(dist==1)
```

Give me only pairs of pixel that are close but I want a group with all the neighbours pixel.

Can you help me or do you have a better solution ?

The first picture of the video, I want to track is this one. It is a falling object. I want to track the edge at the top which is nearly a line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKqug.png)

Comment: can you post a link to the video that you are referring to?

Comment: Hello, I posted the first picture of the video. The edge detection is working pretty well. I want to extract the coordinate of the top left line. They are other edges detected but I want the biggest one to get the best resolution for rotation of my body. I saw that other edges were separated by one or more black pixels. I tried to compute the distance between each edge pixel and to group all the neighbours. Like that, I will have the index of the pixel on the top left line.